# KVO Crashes while using AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, video, avplayer, key-value-observing

I use AVPlayer to play remote videos in Swift, but keep getting these crashes showing up

```
#0
Crashed: com.apple.avfoundation.playerlayer.configuration
EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x000000010522f968
0   libswiftCore.dylib  
__hidden#23281_ line 134
specialized _assertionFailure(StaticString, String, file : StaticString, line : UInt, flags : UInt32) -> Never
1
libswiftFoundation.dylib    
swift_stdlib_bridgeNSErrorToError + 59336
2   libswiftFoundation.dylib    
swift_convertStringToNSString + 559540
3
libswiftFoundation.dylib    
swift_stdlib_bridgeNSErrorToError + 61096
4   Foundation  
-[NSKeyValueUnnestedProperty _givenPropertiesBeingInitialized:getAffectingProperties:] + 200
5
Foundation  
-[NSKeyValueUnnestedProperty _initWithContainerClass:key:propertiesBeingInitialized:] + 152
6   Foundation  
NSKeyValuePropertyForIsaAndKeyPathInner + 284
7   Foundation  
NSKeyValuePropertyForIsaAndKeyPath + 144
8   Foundation  
-[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverRegistration) addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:] + 92
9   AVFoundation    
-[AVPlayerItem addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:] + 368
10  AVFoundation    
-[AVKVODispatcher startObservingValueAtKeyPath:ofObject:options:usingBlock:] + 136
11  AVFoundation    
-[AVKeyPathDependency _startObservingSecondLevelPropertyOnNewCurrentValueForTopLevelDependencyProperty:] + 132
12  AVFoundation    
-[AVKeyPathDependencyManager dependencyHostIsFullyInitialized] + 236
13  AVFoundation    
-[AVKeyPathFlattener initForObservingValueAtKeyPath:onObject:] + 188
14  AVFoundation    
-[AVKVODispatcher startObservingValueAtTwoPartKeyPath:ofObject:options:usingBlock:] + 100
15  AVFoundation    
-[AVKVODispatcher(LegacyCallbackMethod) startObservingObject:weakObserver:forTwoPartKeyPath:options:context:] + 152
16  AVFoundation    
-[AVPlayerLayer _startObservingPlayer:] + 404
17  libdispatch.dylib   
_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
18  libdispatch.dylib   
_dispatch_client_callout + 16
19  libdispatch.dylib   
_dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 528
20  libdispatch.dylib   
_dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 340
21  libdispatch.dylib   
_dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$mp + 404
22  libdispatch.dylib   
_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$mp + 644
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib 
_pthread_wqthread + 932
24
libsystem_pthread.dylib 
start_wqthread + 4
```

I've used traditional KVO by adding an observer to self and overriding the observeValueForKey function and also tried using the new block-based KVO, but something along the lines of this crash always happens (and yes I always remove observers on deinit). This mostly happens on ios 11 devices but I've never gotten this crash on my own device, so I have no idea how it happens.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens or things I can try to fix it? The crash rate on this keeps going up as I add more videos into the app.

Comment: Hey, Did you find the solution to this problem.?
Just in case if you remember.